# what win32 function to call to get the lock screen timeout?

Tags: winapi

I am scratching my head on what win32 function to call in order to get the lock screen timeout. So after you press windows-L and log out from windows and get to the lock screen, after a couple of seconds, the display will turn off ( I think in windows 11 it is after ~ 30 seconds ).

I tried looking at CallNtPowerInformation from PowrProf.dll but couldn't put my finger on what I need.

Can you advise on where to find this informatin?

Regards

Comment: Maybe SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa